# Why does raspividyuv need sudo?

Tags: camera, raspicam, raspivid

I'm running Arch Linux ARM on my RPi 1B. I'm trying to pipe `raspividyuv`'s output to a program that I've written and it seems that I can't run `raspividyuv` without root privileges.

`raspivid` works fine without preceding it with `sudo`:

```
❯ /opt/vc/bin/raspivid -w 640 -h 480 -o - -t 0 -n
```

prints data to stdout as expected.

But when I run

```
❯ /opt/vc/bin/raspividyuv -w 640 -h 480 -o - -t 0 -n
```

I get

```
usrvcsm: [vcsm_malloc_cache]: [757] [mmal_vc_port buffer]: NULL size or invalid device!
usrvcsm: [vcsm_vc_hdl_from_hdl]: [757]: invalid device or handle!
usrvcsm: [vcsm_lock]: [757]: invalid device or invalid handle!
mmal: mmal_vc_shm_alloc: could not allocate 460800 bytes of shared memory (handle 0)
mmal: mmal_vc_port_payload_alloc: vc.ril.camera:out:1(I420): failed to 
allocate 460800 bytes of shared memory
mmal: mmal_pool_initialise_buffer_headers: failed to allocate payload 0/3
mmal: Failed to create buffer header pool for camera still port vc.ril.camera:out:2(OPQV)
fish: '/opt/vc/bin/raspividyuv -w 64...' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

and I don't really understand why the memory couldn't be allocated in this case.

However, running

```
❯ sudo /opt/vc/bin/raspividyuv -w 640 -h 480 -o - -t 0 -n
```

dumps expected data to stdout.

Any ideas why `raspividyuv` behaves like that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem. It turned out to be connected to insufficient access permissions.

In short, I created the following udev rule for `/dev/vcsm`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="vc-sm", MODE="0777"
```

If you are interested in more details I've written a short [blog post](https://protecto.github.io/fixing-raspividyuv-null-size-or-invalid-device-error/) about solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your account to the video group you won't need sudo

Comment: Add more detail to your answer, so that its more useful than a comment. Also how does this answer the question?